# Using support package r4 with monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Do you know any examples, screencasts that document how to develop with support package r4 on "mono for android" ?

I would like to develop a tiny any number views and I'm searching for the proper way to code it, and how include support package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the support package in your app by adding the .jar to your Project and settings its build action to `AndroidJavaSource`. That just leaves actually *using* the package, which largely comes down to some form of JNI. Subclassing is currently more easily done from Java (you can also include `.java` files into your project, and set their build action to `AndroidJavaSource`), allowing you to use `JNIEnv` to interact with your custom Java code.

A future release will simplify things by allowing .jar files to be bound for easy consumption from C#, but that is still being worked on.

Comment: thanks jonp. I find this ans http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Using-the-New-Compatibility-Packages-and-TabActivity-Deprication-td4705492.html

Answer (score 2):

The support package is written in Java, so unless someone ported it to C#, you won't find any. The support/compatibility package comes with source, so you could port the parts you need.